# unable to create alert using powershell Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm running into a weird issue here.
I'm trying to use powershell to create individual availbility alerts for all my storageaccounts.
My code is this

```
$storageaccounts= get-azstorageaccount |get-azresource

$criteria = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "Availability" `
-TimeAggregation average `
-Operator lessthan `
-Threshold 100

foreach ($storageaccount in $storageaccounts){
    Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$storageaccount.Name availbility"  `
    -ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName `
    -WindowSize 00:05:00 `
    -Frequency 00:01:00 `
    -Description "Catching storageaccount availbility" `
    -condition $criteria `
    -ActionGroup $action `
    -Severity 3 `
    -TargetResourceId "$storageaccount.resourceid"
}
```

however I keep getting this error

```
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, 
Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: Bad Request
```

I think the problem is due to

```
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$storageaccount.Name availbility"
```

if i put storageaccount.name into double quotation, i'm getting

```
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResource.Name
```

I also tried this

```
foreach ($storageaccount in $storageaccounts){
$sa=[string]$storageaccount.Name
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$sa availbility"
```

but still gives me the same error

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the command that you are using:

1. Name: You can pass the name as: `"$($storageaccount.StorageAccountName) availbility"`
2. Resource Id: Resource Id which you want to pass is stored in the property "id" of storage account not the "resourceId".

Updated code:

```
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$($storageaccount.StorageAccountName) availbility"  `
-ResourceGroupName $RG.ResourceGroupName `
-WindowSize 00:05:00 `
-Frequency 00:01:00 `
-Description "Catching storageaccount availbility" `
-condition $criteria `
-ActionGroup $action `
-Severity 3 `
-TargetResourceId $storageaccount.id
```

Comment: Spot on! I fixed that on my side as well.